# BrowserRouter is not defined, react-router-dom v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
const routing = () => {
    console.log(BrowserRouter)
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

When I try to use BrowserRouter, it throws `ReferenceError: BrowserRouter is not defined` but when I console log it. It seems to be there.

I'm using version **4.2.2** of `react-router-dom`.

My mind run out of ideas of what could be the reason and I couldnt find anything in google either ;s

Comment: Can you also try to import React `import React from 'react';`. Even functional components like these need it

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import React, and you can put `console.log(BrowserRouter)` in `componentWillMount`;